# MapboxGL JS : clustering polygon instead of point

Tags: javascript, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, mapbox

In mapbox GL JS, the ability to cluster is for point according to the documentation.

But can we cluster polygon ?

Thanks for your input ?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to cluster polygons by "default" when using Mapbox GL JS. As noted [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson-cluster) in the documentation for the `cluster` property of a GeoJSON source:

> If the data is a collection of point features, setting this to true clusters the points by radius into groups.

Since polygons are not of `type` `point` (rather, they are of `type` `polygon`), the `cluster` option cannot be applied. This makes sense when you think about it, because polygons are far too arbitrary to "cluster." Points are well-defined in their shape and scope, meaning that they can be pre-clustered in the source object itself by specifying `cluster: true` as shown in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/) from the Mapbox GL JS examples page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but as pointed, I known that cluster in mapbox is only for point.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another source with points from your polygons:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304794/ogr2ogr-polygon-to-point-with-point-inside-the-polygon

Then just use the source with points for clustering when zoomed out and the source with polygons for rendering those polygons when zoomed in.